# How to add value to string with if statement

Tags: java, reactjs, if-statement

I want to add "/?login=1" to my url if checkbox is True

```
axios.get('https://web.site/api/login/'+username.value+'/'+password.value+'/?login=1')
```

how to modify +'/?login=1'

something like
+ '/?login=1' if checkbox is True

Comment: Please fix your question. The title nor the tag is relevant/clear enough. Please share your attempts

Comment: fixed I guess ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a template literal

```
`https://web.site/api/login/${username.value}/${password.value}${checkbox ? '/?login=1' : ''}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat method in java to add to the string. Alternatively you could also use stringBuilder and then use the 'append' method (which will be better performance wise in most cases. Especially while looping for example)

https://www.javatpoint.com/string-concatenation-in-java

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-stringbuilder-append-method

Example: 
String link = "https://web.site/api/login/'+username.value+'/'+password.value+'/?login=1";

String finishedLink = link.concat("TextToAdd");

axios.get(checkbox.isActivated() ? finishedLink : link);

Let me know if that helps.